# Django + Tastypie - user_logged_in signal doesn't work

Tags: django, authentication, request, signals, tastypie

I have a Tastypie `ModelResource` defining various endpoints which work as expected.

I've now configured this `ModelResource` to have `BasicAuthentication`:

```
class Meta:
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

I've defined a couple of test users through the Django Admin Interface.

As per the [Django 1.7 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/), I've created a `signals.py` in which I register a couple of test signals:

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def on_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    print('******* LOGIN DETECTED *********')

@receiver(request_finished)
def on_request_finished(sender, **kwargs):
    print('******* REQUEST FINISHED *******')
```

This is loaded successfully by my `AppConfig` in `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    verbose_name = 'verbose description of myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
```

I use the `Requests` library to successfully communicate with my API, providing basic authentication credentials for one of my test users:

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, getpass('Enter password: '))
response = requests.get(self.url(endpoint), auth=self.auth, params = params)
```

The `REQUEST FINISHED` print shows in the Django server's output, but `LOGIN DETECTED` does not.

Do we have to manually fire a login signal when using Tastypie, or use some other inbuilt/custom `Authentication` class besides `BasicAuthentication`? In other words, is it expected that the `user_logged_in` signal wouldn't fire automatically?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inspected the Tastypie source code, it ties into the Django auth backend by calling the `authenticate` method, thus doesn't trigger the usual `login` cycle of which `authenticate` is one component. Consequently the `login` method is never called, and thus the `user_logged_in` signal never fires.

I ended up providing the signal myself by extending `BasicAuthentication` and overriding `is_authenticated` like so:

```
class MyBasicAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        orig_user = request.user
        has_authenticated = super(MyBasicAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
        if has_authenticated:
            was_authenticated = orig_user == request.user
            if not was_authenticated:
                user_logged_in.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request, user=request.user)
        return has_authenticated
```