# Django's user_logged_in signal not working when running a test case

Tags: python, django

I have this signal:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def on_user_login(sender, request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
```

It all works when running the app. But when testing, this piece of code fails:

`self.client.force_login(...)`

The test fails with:

> AttributeError: **HttpRequest** object has no attribute **user**

If I remove the signal, that test case runs just fine.

I have Django 1.10

Comment: you imported the signal : -- from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in ??

Comment: I have this in my app.py config:
    ```def ready(self):
        import zdrava_trida.receivers```

Comment: may be import not proper check with   -- >                                                    
[ from django.dispatch import receiver ]                                                             

 -- [ from account.signals import user_logged_in ]                                                         
 -- or --   check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149498/django-tastypie-user-logged-in-signal-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks, neither imports worked. I checked the link you sent me...I guess it could work, BUT I don't think this is a default and wanted behaviour. I must be missing something...I don't want to make a subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my test I was testing one of the admin views. I wanted to login the user first before doing this change. What I did not realize was that I really wanted to test just the admin view, not logging in.

So instead of using client for testing, I used `RequestFactory` and passed the user in it. No logging in necessary.

The original error was due to the fact that `client` in django tests does not add the user to the request.